# Does "recenter" have a British spelling?

Tags: spelling, dialect

I know that "center" and "centre" are the respective American and British spellings of the word, but is "recenter" spelt "recentre" in the British way, or not?  I tried to Google for "recentre", but no dictionary came up with it.  Actually, is that even a real word?  I'm trying to get the word meaning

> to bring back to the middle after being away from it

Comment: Did you try to find out if *recenter* (not *recentre*) was a word? That would at least answer the first part of your question :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: after looking up other sites, it looks like it doesn't exist.  What would be a word or phrase that suits what I'm looking for (Google really isn't helpful for these things)?

Comment: [*Recenter*](http://onelook.com/?w=recenter&ls=a) is definitely a word.  Collins lists [*recentre*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recentre) as its British spelling, for what it's worth.

Comment: I suppose it might not be in that many dictionaries because *re-* is still relatively productive, and it's compositional with *center* (or *centre*).

Comment: I know the noun "centre" is spelt "centre" in British English, but what about the verb?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm In British English both noun and verb forms are spelt the same, "centre".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You, like the OP, could answer that out for yourself by consulting a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/centre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google [ngram viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recenter,%20recentre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

it does exist; it's used about 1/5 as much as `recenter'.

but the pattern of ["center" and "centre"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=center,%20centre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is very different over time.

Odd.... and fuel for thought!

Comment: Also interesting to look at [the American corpus alone](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=center%2Ccentre&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) which shows that "center" only came to dominate US english a little over a century ago.

Comment: Thanks - just looking at one more site _obviously_ wasn't enough!

Comment: @NigelHarper That's because of [Noah Webster's spelling reforms](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/spelling-reform.htm).  Pre-Webster, we all used *centre*, and even post-Webster it took some time for *center* to catch on in the States.

Answer (score 2):

If you're British, you can certainly [recentre an image](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22recentre%20the%20sights%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22recentre%20the%20image%22&tbm=bks) (on a display, for example). Americans, obviously, would [recenter](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22recentre%20the%20sights%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22recenter%20the%20image%22&tbm=bks) it. That's in the sense of *to place or fix in the centre (again).*

There was never a time when anyone on either side of the Atlantic would have spelt *centre/center* differently for verb/noun senses; the derived *re-* forms for verbs simply reflect the relevant "standard".

I suppose because I'm more accustomed to the British spelling, the American version puts me in mind of a non-native speaker's attempt to convey *more recent*. That's a complete no-no today, of course, but it [***was*** sometimes used that way](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22recenter%20date%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) a couple of centuries ago.